# Configure Zulip chat

Tags: bash, software-installation, environment-variables

I am trying to install Zulip chat on Ubuntu but get this error:

```
bash: ./scripts/setup/install: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with a suggestion!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the shebang line (the first line of the script, starting with `#!`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what you are trying to do, what you are trying to install; ii) show us the first few lines of the `./scripts/setup/install` script (run `head ./scripts/setup/install` and paste the output into your question, using the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code) and iii) tell us your Linux distribution.

Comment: I have to install Zulip chat on ubuntu and I Change to the zulip directory and then run the ‘install’ script to start the installation script.

Comment: root@dev-62:/tmp/zulip# ./scripts/setup/install
-bash: ./scripts/setup/install: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Comment: As we said before, please ***[edit]*** your question and add these details. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. And you still haven't told us what this `install` script is or where you found it or shown us the first few lines.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on Ubuntu (or Debian and probably other Debian-based systems), follow the instructions on the [Zulip page](https://zulipchat.com/help/desktop-app-install-guide):

> 1. Enter the following commands into a terminal:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 69AD12704E71A4803DCA3A682424BE5AE9BD10D9
>    echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/zulip/debian/ stable main" | \
>    sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zulip.list
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt install zulip
>    ```
>
>    These commands set up the Zulip Desktop apt repository and its signing key, and then install the Zulip client.
> 2. Run Zulip from your app launcher, or with `zulip` from a terminal.
>
> The app will be updated automatically to future versions when you do a regular software update on your system, e.g. with sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.

For other Linux systems, the same page recommends:

> 1. Download [Zulip for Linux](https://zulipchat.com/apps/linux).
> 2. Make the file executable, with `chmod a+x Zulip-x.x.x-x86_64.AppImage` from a terminal (replace x.x.x with the actual name of the downloaded file).
> 3. Run the file from your app launcher, or from a terminal.
>
> No installer is necessary; this file is the Zulip app. The app will update automatically to future versions.

---

I don't see an `install` file anywhere, so I have no idea why you are even trying that approach. However, the error you get means that the script is trying to run using `/usr/bin/env` which, very strangely, doesn't seem to have the executable bit set. So make the program executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/env
```

And then try again. Alternatively, if the script is an `sh` script, you can fix that by running `sh ./install` but, again, we can't be sure since you haven't shown us the script.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. And now I can fix it.

Comment: I want to create a new user on zulip chat but I can't find the way to create.

Comment: @lysopheap please post a new question for that. I have never used zulip, I didn't even know it existed before reading your question.

Comment: The question seems to be for installing the Zulip Chat server, your answer pertains to the installation of Zulip Chat desktop app.

Comment: The link to the actual installation steps is here https://zulip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/production/install.html#step-2-install-zulip

Comment: @RajuDevidas  great! Could you post an answer explaining how to install it?